# Showing that the lower and upper sum of the function is not equal.

Tags: integration, solution-verification

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $
>
> $$
> f(x) =
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   x & \mbox{if } x  \in I \cap \mathbb{Q} \\
>   x^2 & \mbox{if } x  \in I \backslash \mathbb{Q} 
>  \end{array}
> \right.$$
>
> We need to show that the following function is not integrable.

Suppose that the following function is integrable then $U(P,f) = L(P,f)$.

Let $(P_n)$ be a sequence of partitions on $[0,1] $ such that $||P_n|| \to 0$.We also know that $\mbox{lim}_{n \to \infty}(U(P_n,f)) = U(P,f)$ and $\mbox{lim}_{n \to \infty}(L(P_n,f)) = L(P,f)$ .

Now we know that $x>x^2, \forall x \in [0,1] $ and both functions are monotonically increasing.

Let P be a partition on $[0,1]$ such that $nh = 1$ then $h = \frac{1}{n}$.

So $P_n = (0, \frac{1}{n} , \frac{2}{n} ,\cdots , 1)$ .

We know that $\mbox{lim}_{n \to \infty}U(P_n,f) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}sup(f(x))_{x \in [x_{r} , x_{r+1} ] }\frac{1}{n}= (\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{3}{n} + \cdots + \frac{n-1}{n} + 1)\frac{1}{n} = (1 + 2 + \cdots + n )\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2.n^2} = \mbox{lim}_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2}$

Given the interval $[\frac{r}{n} , \frac{r+1}{n}]$ ,

$inf(f(x))_{[x \in \frac{r}{n} ,\frac{r+1}{n}]} = (t_r)^2 > \frac{r}{n}$ where $t_r$ is irrational.

Then $\mbox{lim}_{n \to \infty}L(P_n,f) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}inf(f(x))_{x \in [x_{r} , x_{r+1} ] }\frac{1}{n}= (0 + t_1^2 + \cdots (t_{n-1})^2)\frac{1}{n}) <  (0 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{3}{n} + \cdots + \frac{n-1}{n})\frac{1}{n} = (1 + 2 + \cdots + n-1 )\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2.n^2} = \mbox{lim}_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2}$

Hence the two limits does not converge to the same point.

Is this ok?

Comment: Your first equality is $U(P,f)=L(P,f)$. Are you claiming that, if $f$ is integrable, then this holds for *every* partition $P$?

Comment: I am trying to claim $U(P,f) =\frac{1}{2}$ and $L(P,f) < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Your first sentence after the statement of the problem is “Suppose that the following function is integrable then $U(P,f) = L(P,f)$”. What does this *mean*?

Comment: I am trying to find a contradiction to that statement.Yes $U(P,f) = inf\{U(P_i,f) ,\forall P_i \mbox{ partition on } [0,1]\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer looks great. However, we can be more precise when calculating $L(P_n,f)$. Note that for any interval $[a,b]\subseteq [0,1]$ we have that
\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)= a^2. 
\end{equation}
To see why, first note that inequality clearly holds, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\geq a^2.
\end{equation}
If $a\notin\mathbb{Q}$ then $f(a)=a^2$ so we are done. If $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ then let $a_n\to a$ such that $a_n\in[a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. We have
\begin{equation} 
\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\leq f(a_n)= a_n^2,
\end{equation}
so taking $n\to \infty$ we prove the claim. As a result,
\begin{equation}
L(P_n,f)= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1n \inf_{x\in[\frac{i}{n}, \frac{i+1}{n}]}f(x)= \frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{n^2}= \frac{1}{n^3}(1^2+ \ldots+ (n-1)^2)= \frac{1}{n^3}\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}. 
\end{equation}
Taking $n\to\infty$ we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}L(P_n,f)= \frac13.
\end{equation}

Comment: Okay i got it .Thank you so much